# Use CLS with Sequelize Unmanaged transactions

Tags: mysql, node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js, cls-hooked

I am writing unit tests for my code and wish to use `transactions` to prevent any stray data between tests.

The code uses `Sequelize` ORM for all interactions with the database. Since changing the actual code is not an option, I would be using `cls-hooked` to maintain transaction context instead of passing transaction to all the queries. There is a problem, however. On reading the official documentation and trying to go about it, the above approach seems to only work for managed transactions.

So far, the test code looks somewhat like:

```
test("Test decription", async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
            //Actual test code
        });
    } catch (error) {
        //Do nothing if query rolled back
    }
});
```

What I intend to achieve (for obvious reasons):

```
let t;

beforeEach(async () => {
    t = await sequelize.transaction();
});

test("Test decription", async () => {
    //Actual test code
});

afterEach(async () => {
    await t.rollback();
});
```

Is this possible? If yes, any help in implementing this would be appreciated.

Comment: *obvious reasons* - what reasons? What exactly is the problem with first snippet?

Comment: @EstusFlask  For every test, the first approach would require initiating a transaction and adding a catch block to the test itself. The second approach would lead to a cleaner test code and much easier handling as well as avoid code redundancy.

Comment: Saw a similar CLS question a while ago but can't find it. I guess the solution is what's discussed here, https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/issues/44 .

Answer (score 1):

It's true that Sequelize doesn't automatically pass transactions to queries when you're using unmanaged transactions. But you can manually set the transaction property on the CLS namespace, just like Sequelize does on a managed transaction:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v6.9.0/lib/transaction.js#L135

```js
namespace.run(() => {
    namespace.set('transaction', transaction);
    /* run code that does DB operations */
});
```

This is tricky for tests because `describe()` calls can be nested and each can have their own `beforeAll()`/`afterAll()` and `beforeEach()`/`afterEach()` hooks. To do this right, each `before` hook needs to set up a nested transaction and the corresponding `after` hook should roll it back. In addition, the test case itself needs to run in a nested transaction so that its DB operations don't leak into other tests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem -- after much Googling, I found this closed [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5432) where they indicate that unmanaged transactions aren't supported by design

Answer (score 0):

For anyone from the future:

I was facing the above problem and found a way to fix it with a helper function and cls-hooked.

```
const transaction = async (namespace: string, fn: (transaction: Transaction) => unknown) => {
  const nameSpace = createNamespace(namespace);
  db.Sequelize.useCLS(nameSpace);
  const sequelize = db.sequelize;

  const promise = sequelize.transaction(async (transaction: Transaction) => {
    try {
      await fn(transaction);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
    throw new TransactionError();
  });

  await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow(TransactionError);
  destroyNamespace(namespace);
};
```

What the above code does is creating a cls namespace and transaction that will be discarded after the test run, the TransactionError is thrown to ensure the entire transaction is always rolled back on each test run.

Usage on tests would be:

```
describe('Transaction', () => {
  test('Test', async () => {
    await transaction('test', async () => {
      // test logic here
    });
  });
});
```